# TS 2322 Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have Angular 12 project which has typescript 4.2.3
I'm getting bunch of these errors. In this case, I'm passing appLang parameter to child component.

So here's my html:

<app-bankcard-call-flows [appLang]="getLanguage()">

I'm trying to pull value from the coordinating component:

```
  public getLanguage() {
    this.appLang = this.language;
   }
```

I'm getting error:

```
TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'.
<app-bankcard-call-flows [appLang]="getLanguage()"></app-bankcard-call-flows>
```

Comment: So for starters, it looks like you instead want like `public getLanguage = (): string => this.language;` so the value actually **returns** to that input....but that's assuming that `appLang` is an actual `@Input` of of that component it's declared on, but overall I'm guessing that's not your only issue though, but should get you past this current hump....unless you're expecting `[appLang]` to magically have some context within the scope of the component declaring that var or something, hard to say with such little to go on.

Comment: Side note, careful when you do it this way instead of just having a var set it, put a console log on there and make sure you aren't just constantly firing off the method every change detection cycle unless you're using .onPush strategy, your app will get noisy quick....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `getLanguage()` does not return anything so you're essentially passing `void` to the `[appLang]` input while it expects a string.

Either use `[appLang]="appLang"` or change the method to return the `appLang`:

```
public getLanguage(): string {
    return this.language;
}
```